# Return 'this' chosen option value from array

Tags: jquery

I've tried using each and grep but i dont think these are the right events needed in this instance

This is what I've started with:

```
var $children = $("select[name^='children'] option:selected")
    .map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
```

which returns : ["1", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1"]

```
$("#room").on("change", $children, function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

This returns white space in the console (i.e a blank white line), I'm confused as to what that is too.

EDIT:

Its one of 3 fields in a container and this container may be cloned by the user upto 4 times. Here is just one field, the one in question.

I'm bascially just wanting to return a number.

HTML:

```
 <select name="children1" id="children1">
     <option value="0">0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like, and what are you trying to return exactly ?

Comment: So now you have three selects, with a maximum of four clones of each, and assuming they all have the same name and ID (<- not valid), which one are you trying to get the value from ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v5y4V/ Can you update the fiddle to illustrate the problem

Comment: i agree with @adeneo that this needs some more context. Maybe a larger section of HTML or when exactly you are trying to retrieve the data. Are you trying to do this as and when one of the selets change, is this going off to another screen. Your question is quite vague.

Comment: if the container is a "clonable" container, don't use `id` and use `class` instead

Comment: Rash assumption..The id and names increment on duplication, so they are all different. The value: Any time the user clicks any of the children fields i then want some code to run.Thanks.

Comment: There is no fields, they are called options, and you don't really click them, you change the value of the select element, and that is the element to target, and since they are cloned, they are dynamically inserted etc. I added an answer with the code, try that.

Answer (score 1):

> Any time the user clicks any of the children fields i then want some
>   code to run.

I'll assume that means, anytime the value of a select changes, get it's value, and as they are cloned, I'll assume they are inserted dynamically :

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name^="children"]', function() {
     console.log( this.value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give the selected option

```
$('select[name^="children"] option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var selected = $("select[name^='children']")
    .map(function () {
    return this.value.length ? this.value : undefined;
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pz5w8/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want get the drop-down value selected by a user. To do so whenever a value is selected, you need to attach a `change` event handler to the drop downs.

**Example:**

```
$("select[name^='children']").change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    alert(selectedValue);
});
```

This should work with multiple drop-downs as well. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DdPw/1/).

**Note:**

You can also use `.text()` in this case, but it's recommended that you use `.val()` because that works for all input elements, whereas `.text()` can sometimes give you incorrect results because it returns the combined text content of the matched elements and their descendants.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:

**CODE**

```
$(document).on("change", "select", function(){
    alert($(this).val() + " - " + $(this).attr("id")); 
});
```

this will trigger the alert every time you select an option, even on a newly "cloned" select. See the fiddle for a working example:

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/nndKx/1/